# Rustで、構造体のメソッドを受け取る関数はどのようにすれば作れますか？

Tags: rust

Rustを勉強中の初心者です。
構造体のメソッドを受け取る関数を作成したいのですが、うまく関数に渡せないので、ご助言をお願いします。

**試したこと**
「関数を受け取る関数 - Rust by Example」
http://doc.rust-jp.rs/rust-by-example-ja/fn/closures/input_functions.html
を参考にして、下記のコードを作成しました。

```
struct Foo {
  s: String,
}
impl Foo {
  fn method(&self, s: &String) {
    println!("{}", s);
  }
}

fn function(s: &String) {
  println!("{}", s);
}

fn execute<F>(f: F, s: &String)
where
  F: Fn(&String),
{
  f(s);
}

fn main() {
  let s = String::from("function!");
  execute(function, &s);
  // >>> function!

  let s = String::from("method!");
  let foo = Foo { s };
  execute(foo.method, &foo.s);
  // >>> Error
}
```

**結果**

`execute(function, &s);` は実行できていますが、 `execute(foo.method, &foo.s);` の部分で下記のエラーが出ます。

```
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `method` on type `Foo`
  --> src/main.rs:35:15
   |
35 |   execute(foo.method, &foo.s);
   |               ^^^^^^ method, not a field
   |
help: use parentheses to call the method
   |
35 |   execute(foo.method(_), &foo.s);
   |                     +++
```

しかしながら、やりたいことは `execute(foo.method(&foo.s));` のように「メソッドの返り値を関数に渡す」ことではありません。

構造体のメソッドを関数に渡すには、どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

クロージャを指定すれば、（記述量は増えますが）やりたいことは実現できます。

```rust
execute(|x| foo.method(x), &foo.s);
```

---

関数そのものを渡したいということならば、次のような記述もあります。
ただ、そもそも `method` 関数は `self` と `s` の2つの引数を取る関数ですので、メソッドを受け取る関数に修正が必要です。

```rust
fn execute2<F>(f: F, foo: &Foo, s: &String)
where
  F: Fn(&Foo, &String),
{
  f(foo, s);
}

execute2(Foo::method, &foo, &foo.s); // -> method!
```

Comment: 動きました。クロージャの方法が最も修正が少なくて済みました。また、「&selfもmethodの引数の一つである点を踏まえて、受け取る関数と渡す関数の引数の型を揃える必要がある」ということですね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

ご質問のコードでは、`execute(foo.method, &foo.s)`のところの他にもう1つ問題があります。順番に直していきましょう。

まず`execute`関数の引数`f: F`ですが、

```rust
    // 引数として &String を1つだけ取る
    F: Fn(&String),
```

これは`Fn(&String)`型です。つまり引数を1つだけ取るクロージャーです。

ところが`Foo`の`method`メソッドは以下の定義になっており、引数を2つとります。

```rust
impl Foo {
    // 引数として self: &Foo と s: &Stringの2つを取る
    fn method(&self, s: &String) {
```

`method`は`Fn(&Foo, &String)`型になるので、`execute`関数の引数`f`（`Fn(&String)`型）には渡せません。

まずはこれを修正しましょう。

そもそも`Foo`は`s: String`というフィールドを持っていますので、`fn method(&self, s: &String)`のように、もう1つの`s`を引数に取る必要はありません。以下のように変更します。

**変更前**

```rust
impl Foo {
    // 引数として self: &Foo と s: &Stringの2つを取る
    fn method(&self, s: &String) {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

**変更後**

```rust
impl Foo {
    // 引数として self: &Foo を1つだけ取る
    fn method(&self) {
        // フィールドsを使う
        println!("{}", self.s);
    }
}
```

これで`method`は引数を1つだけ取る`Fn(&Foo)`型になりました。

次に`execute`関数を修正します。第2引数`s: &String`を、任意の型`T`を受け付けるように変更します。

```rust
fn execute<F, T>(f: F, t: &T)
where
    F: Fn(&T),
{
    f(t);
}
```

こうすることで`Fn(&Foo)`型の`method`と、`Fn(&String)`型の`function`の両方を引数に取れるようになります。

最後に元々エラーになっていた、以下のコードを修正しましょう。

```rust
execute(foo.method, &foo.s);
```

Rustのメソッドは関連関数の一種にすぎません。`foo`が`Foo`型のとき`foo.method()`と書くと、コンパイラーは`Foo::method(&foo)`と書かれたのだと解釈します。そのため以下のように書けます。

```rust
// Fooのmethodメソッドを第1引数に、&Fooを第2引数にする
execute(Foo::method, &foo);
```

これでコンパイルできるようになります。実行結果は以下のとおりです。

```
$ cargo run
function!
method!
```

全体のコードは以下のようになります。

```rust
struct Foo {
    s: String,
}

impl Foo {
    fn method(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.s);
    }
}

fn function(s: &String) {
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn execute<F, T>(f: F, t: &T)
where
    F: Fn(&T),
{
    f(t)
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("function!");
    execute(function, &s);
    // >>> function!

    let s = String::from("method!");
    let foo = Foo { s };
    execute(Foo::method, &foo);
    // >>> method!
}
```

Comment: 動きました。確かにメンバ変数を引数として受け取るメソッドは冗長でした。すみません。Fnトレイトの引数の型をジェネリック型にすることもできるんですね。そんな発想は全くなかったです。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。